# Can't change column's type in Hive

Tags: hive

I want to change some column's type in Hive table.

First, this is a description to my hive table:

```
hive (indicateurs)> describe adataindicateursf;
OK
nom                     string                  from deserializer
mod                     string                  from deserializer
val1                    string                  from deserializer
val2                    string                  from deserializer
val3                    string                  from deserializer
datar                   string                  from deserializer
cdb                     string                  from deserializer
met                     string                  from deserializer
env                     string                  from deserializer
ncre                    string                  from deserializer
app                     string                  from deserializer
type                    string                  from deserializer
```

Then to change val2's type to integer and val2's type to double.

```
ALTER TABLE adataindicateursf CHANGE val2 val2 int AFTER val1;

ALTER TABLE adataindicateursf CHANGE val3 val3 double AFTER val2;
```

But, there wasn't any change :

```
describe adataindicateursf;
OK
nom                     string                  from deserializer
mod                     string                  from deserializer
val1                    string                  from deserializer
val2                    string                  from deserializer
val3                    string                  from deserializer
datar                   string                  from deserializer
cdb                     string                  from deserializer
met                     string                  from deserializer
env                     string                  from deserializer
ncre                    string                  from deserializer
app                     string                  from deserializer
type                    string                  from deserializer
```

What's the problem here ?

Comment: are you using `use databasename` before alter query? Also try alter, without using *AFTER*

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela, yes I am using  `use databasename`. I also tried without using `AFTER –`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this:  
ALTER TABLE adataindicateursf CHANGE val2 val2 int;  
ALTER TABLE adataindicateursf CHANGE val3 val3 double;  
if the above query are not working then try this:  
set hive.metastore.disallow.incompatible.col.type.changes=false   
when you set the properties then the types of columns in Metastore can be changed from any type to any other type.
```